# Phone Gap OnDeviceReady not Working

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I want to put ads in my app. The app itself works fine but it does not fire the callback bound to the event *ondeviceready*. [This is a past of my code](http://pastebin.com/G4gtQsBT) and [this is a past of my config](http://pastebin.com/ATzp5bEU).

Comment: Just add `cordova.js` and your code will work.

Comment: thank you that helped it fires up the ondeviceready now, but still it wont show ads

Comment: set `try` `catch` condition into your `initAd()` function you may get some error or info of why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are naming your function onDeviceReady, but calling it with OnDeviceReady. Rename your function to OnDeviceReady (capital "On").

Comment: A long shot, but try adding the addlistener line AFTER the OnDeviceReady function. It is possible that the event is firing before the function is "created".

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to say without seeing the whole project. :( If you are using something like Visual Studio to test you can see what errors might be showing up in the console. If not, at the very least add some more alerts at different places to see what code is actually executing.

Comment: yaeh I basicly have nothing to debug, just my phone to see if it works

Comment: the only file I have in my projekt is the config an icon.png and a index.html that is it nothing more nothing less, besides some random folders with no content

Comment: Are you able to even see a page load? Like, is the app even running? Maybe through some text or something into the HTML to make sure the page is actually loading, because Cordova might not be initializing at all.

Comment: I found the error i did not have the cardova.js in the file